# I am struggling here on getting an array to print in the proper format from a method call

Tags: arrays, methods, printing, swap

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = new int[] {2, 5, 9, 8, 12};
    System.out.println("Starting array is: " + Arrays.toString(values));
    System.out.println("Swap first and last yields: " + firstLastSwap(Values));
// The print using the firstLastSwap method comes out jumbled with letters and numbers.
}
public static int[] firstLastSwap(int[] values)
{
    int temp = values[0];
    values[0] = values[values.length - 1];
    values[values.length - 1] = temp;
    return(values); // Can I make this return as a normal looking array?
}
```

The ouput for the first println always makes a lovely looking array - [2, 5, 9, 8, 12]. However, after I swap the first and last elements the return prints something like this - 8fl9lj. Random nonesense. Despite over an hour of google I can not find a simple way to fix this problem.

Comment: replace **firstLastSwap(values)** with **Arrays.toString(firstLastSwap(values))**

Comment: I am almost upset it was that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting second array to String in System.out.println statement. You need to replace the firstLastSwap(Values) with **Arrays.toString(firstLastSwap(Values)))**